# Trigometric equation $n\sin\theta-\sin(2\theta)=\alpha$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ given that $n\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$, and $\alpha>0$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve

\begin{align*}
n\sin\theta-\sin(2\theta)=\alpha
\end{align*}

for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ given that $n\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$, and $\alpha>0$ is such that at least one solution is guaranteed to exist. Maybe its not possible?

Comment: No solution for n = 2, $\alpha = 3$. You will need an upper bound on $\alpha$ for a given n or range of n values by the look of it (graph).

Comment: Experimenting, $n>\alpha$ might work.

Comment: The equation comes out of the Lagrange conditions for solving an optimization problem. I have simplified it somewhat. $\alpha$ is a product of two parameters, one of which is the Langrange multiplier. Essentially, we are free to chose $\alpha$ so that the equation has a solution

Comment: If you are free to choose $\alpha$, then set $\alpha=n\sin\theta-\sin2\theta$ for some $\theta$ !!

Comment: @Yves Daoust That would be nice :) I am not that free to choose. I have $N$ equations like this one. Each equation has a $\theta_i$ and an  $\alpha_i=\lambda c_i$, where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. Then I also have a constraint $\sum_{i=1}^N\theta_i=\pi$.

Comment: @user98563: that's a different question, you should have said it upfront.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. Sorry, I thought it would be easier to find a solution if I simplified it. A solution to this equation for $\alpha$ that does not depend on $\theta$ yields a solution to the optimization problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the tangent half-angle substitution, you would end with
$$\alpha -2(n-2) t+2 \alpha  t^2-2(n+2) t^3+\alpha  t^4=0$$ which can be solved exactly using radicals (probably messy but this is the formal solution).

**Edit**

Assuming that $\frac \alpha n$ is "small", we can build the series expansion of the lhs and then use series reversion to get
$$\theta=t+\frac{(n-8) }{6 (n-2)}t^3+\frac{3 \left(n^2-14 n+64\right) }{40
   (n-2)^2}t^5+\frac{\left(5 n^3-100 n^2+788 n-2560\right) }{112
   (n-2)^3}t^7+O\left(t^9\right)$$ where $t=\frac{\alpha }{n-2}$.

Trying for $n=10$ and $\alpha=8$, the above expansion would give $\theta=\frac{14453}{13440}=1.075$ while the exact solution is $1.082$.